# Wordpress Echoing Urls Strangely

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In a section of code I'm attempting to show a menu title and the associated featured image.

The featured image is going to be the background of a `<div>` element, like this:

```
echo '<div style="width:100%;background-image:url("'.$thumbnail[0].'")"><h1>'. $menu->title .'</h1></div></a>';
```

I've tried two different method of getting the URL:

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($menu->object_id, 'full');

$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $menu->object_id ), 'full' );
```

Whenever any of these urls are rendered into the browser the url is completely garbled from this:

```
"http://localhost:8085/wp-content/uploads/D_DSC0130.png"
```

Into this:

```
url(" http:="" localhost:8085="" wp-content="" uploads="" d_dsc0130.png")"="">
```

I've not seen any posts or discussion talking about anything similar.  The site is hosted in IIS and running on PHP 7.1.7.

I have already attempted to escape the returned value with this:

```
echo '<div style="width:100%;background-image:url("'.esc_url($thumbnail[0]).'")"><h1>'. $menu->title .'</h1></div></a>';
```

if I echo this, the URL is fine and the image is displayed on the page:

```
echo '<img src="'.esc_url($image).'" />';
```

How can I correct the rendered values in the `div` version?

Answer (score 0):

If the url is being returned ok then you probably need to escape it to output properly

```
echo '<div style="width:100%;background-image:url("'.esc_url($thumbnail[0]).'")"><h1>'. $menu->title .'</h1></div></a>';
```